# Appcompat-v7 works fine with gradle commands, but shows error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am migrating an android project from ActionbarSherlock to Appcompat-v7.

I have added the appcompat-v7 library in build.gradle using the following code-

```
compile 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

The code compiles fine using gradle commands in terminal, and generates debug-apk as well. However, Android Studio 1.5 RC1 shows the following errors during compile-

```
/Users/Projects/PageTurner/res/values/styles.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I had similar issue, currently I have used `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'` in my `build.gradle` and done 'Sync now' - and things are working fine.

Comment: First of all use the last version of appcompat: 23.1.1

Comment: I tried using both the latest and 22.+ ,then it shows many errors at appcompat library. This issue is really bugging me a lot. I uninstalled Android Studion, cleaned the caches and reinstall to get no different result.

Comment: Sure glad it isn't just me, maybe those bone heads will fix this. At least my existing projects still build okay.